# What tests should be done before running a multiple regression model on balanced panel data?

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics, panel-data, eviews

I am currently a graduate student working on writing my master’s thesis. The master's thesis includes conducting a regression model on a set of bank data, which includes financial indicators for the dependent variable and the independent variable.

I am now working on conducting regression according to three models (common effect model - fixed effect model - random effect model) because the data I have is balanced panel data. Using the Eviews program. My question is what tests should I do before starting to apply the regression model. For example, stability testing or other tests?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in one of the published scientific papers. Which contains a diagram of the necessary procedures for this
[image]